# How do you evaluate $a_n = \frac{n!}{2j}((-1)^n \frac{1}{(-1)^{n+1}j^{n+1}}+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{j^{n+1}}$ for odd and even cases?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose n $\in  \Bbb N$ and $j \in  \Bbb C$ is a complex number. Suppose I have defined the sequence:

$a_n = \frac{n!}{2j}((-1)^n \frac{1}{(-1)^{n+1}j^{n+1}}+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{j^{n+1}}$

This sequence simplifies when n is odd or even.  For example if n is odd, $(-1)^n=-1$ and if n is even then $(-1)^n=1$.

What I'm confused about is how to handle the cases for the complex number $j$. 
So if n is odd, $j^n=j$ or $j^n=-j$

If n is even, $j^n=1$ or $j^n=-1$

Correct?

So if consider two cases (n is odd and n is even), then each of these cases would have two more sub-cases, right? That means the sequence $a_n$ could have 4 possible values.

So based on the above logic, here are my 4 cases:

Case 1: n is even and $j^n=1$. Then $ a_n = \frac{n!}{2j}(-\frac{1}{j}-\frac{1}{j}) = n!$

Case 2: n is even and $j^n=-1$ Then $ a_n = \frac{n!}{2j}(\frac{1}{j}+\frac{1}{j}) = -n!$

I have checked the answer and apparently my answer for Case 2 is wrong. It's still supposed to be $n!$ just like case 1.

So I am confused.  My suspicion is my confusion has to do with the periodicity of exponentiation of a singleton complex number, but I'm not sure.

Would appreciate any input from the community.

Comment: Does $j = \sqrt{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $j \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $j^2 = -1$,

$$a_n := \frac{n!}{2j}\left(\frac{(-1)^n }{(-1)^{n+1}j^{n+1}}+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{j^{n+1}}\right)$$

This is the same as

$$a_n = -\frac{n!}{2j}\left(\frac{1}{j^{n+1}}+\frac{(-1)^{n}}{j^{n+1}}\right) = -\frac{n!j^n}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(-1)^n(-1)}+\frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^n(-1)}\right) = \frac{n!j^n}{2}((-1)^n+1)$$

> $$a_n = \frac{n!j^n}{2}(1+(-1)^n)$$

Using that we see that for $n$ odd we have $a_n = 0$ and for $n$ even we get

$$a_{2k} = \frac{(2k)!(j^2)^k}{2}2 = (-1)^k(2k)!$$